# JS: HTML is not dynamically changing

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am building an web that allows user to like a post when they click a button. CreateLike function calls API and creates a like object however, I would like to have the number of likes updated right away without reloading. I built another API that returns the number of likes for a post. Function LikeCount should put the number of likes into the p tag. It works initially when I load the page however, the value does not change when I click the button even though I can see that the API is called. (After reloading the page the number changes as expected) What am I doing wrong?

I have this HTML:

```
<p class="like-count" id={{post.id}}></p>
<script>LikeCount({{post.id}});</script>
<button type="button" class="btn-like" onclick="CreateLike({{user.id}},{{post.id}})"></button>
```

with JS functions:

```
            function CreateLike (userid,postid) {
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = "{% url 'likes' %}";
                var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken')
                xhr.open("POST", url, true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken",'{{ csrf_token }}')
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { 
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        console.log(json.email + ", " + json.name)
                    }
                }
                var data = JSON.stringify({csrfmiddlewaretoken:csrftoken,"user":userid,"post":postid});
                xhr.send(data);
                LikeCount(postid);
            }
            function LikeCount(postid) {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = "{% url 'likecount' id=112233 %}".replace("112233", postid);

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    myFunction(myArr);
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                xmlhttp.send();

                function myFunction(arr) {
                    var out = arr.like_count;
                    document.getElementById(postid).innerHTML = out;
                }
            }
```

Like count API looks like this:

```
{
    "like_count": 1
}
```

Comment: Please define "not working". Also, what templating engine are you using?

Comment: you can implement an optimistic update (increment the like counter right the way) and then perform the HTTP request. if not succeeded, restore the state before the change

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sorry for not being clean. It does not show the returned number in the <p> tag.

Comment: @AngelSalazar I forgot to mention that I call the likecount when the page loads however, when the button is clicked I can see that the api gets called but the number in the p tag does not change. It changes after reloading

Comment: @Roitko the question is much clearer now.

Comment: @AluanHaddad sorry for not mentioning the full picture from the beginning!

Comment: One problem is that `CreateLike` calls `LikeCount` _before_ the API request to create the like has completed. I would expect it to render eventually, but it is absolutely a bug. `LikeCount` should be called in the `onreadstatechange` calllback in `CreateLike`. Also, you have implicitly declared global variables that _will_ cause serious, unpredictable problems.` To remedy this, add the line `"use strict";` to the very top of your script file, or at the top of each function, and fix any errors.

Comment: That's because you're immediately expecting 'GET' request to fetch you the updated likes after you've sent the 'POST' request.

Comment: @AluanHaddad changed it as you said to `xhr.onreadystatechange = LikeCount(postid);` but I can still see that the GET API gets called before the POST one, any idea why?

Comment: I didn't mean `xhr.onreadystatechange = LikeCount(postid)` that is broken and code. I meant place the invocation of  `LikrCount` inside of the existing callback function after you have parsed the JSON

Comment: @AluanHaddad found a solution thanks to you:                 `xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 201) {
                    var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    LikeCount(myArr.post);
                    }
                };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) {
     LikeCount(); //Put your get like count here
    } else {
      // Handle Errors
    }
  }
```

Call `LikeCount` only after receiving the response of your `POST` request. Right now you're immediately sending a `GET` request without ensuring if the previous `POST` request got completed.

Comment: Shouldnt the status be 201? As it is a post request and if it is successful the status is 201

Comment: I tried this and now the GET request is not being called

Comment: @Roitko Put the break point in the above method and see what `status` you're getting. Then you can verify if the conditions are met to call `likeCount()`

Comment: @Roitko `xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE` is this meeting in your case?

Comment: `xhr.readyState` is 1 => OPENED. I called it after `xhr.send(data);`

Comment: Did you remove `LikeCount(postid);` from your original code after `xhr.send(data);`?

Comment: Yes, the code is now as following: `xhr.send(data);
                if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    var status = xhr.status;
                    if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) {
                    LikeCount(postid); //Put your get like count here
                    } 
                    else {
                    // Handle Errors
                    }
                }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213945/discussion-between-rahul-dwivedi-and-roitko).

Comment: correct `postid` in LikeCount(postid);. That should be coming from the `response`. Come on chat.

Answer (score 0):

Added

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 201) {
    var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    LikeCount(myArr.post);
    }
};
```

before

```
xhr.send(data);
```

and it fixed the issue.